# Fixing Disappearing Zeros

Tags: java

I wanted to divide the integer and store it in an array

For Ex:1000000000000 into two indexes

arr[0]=1000000
arr[1]=000000

but arr[1] stores it as 0 instead of 0000000.

I wanted to perform some operations with it,so i needed 7 zeros in it ,instead of 1 zero.

Is it achievable in some way ?

Comment: Store it as a `String`. Java int `0` is just `0` (regardless of leading `0`s).

Comment: An `int` is a _number_, not a representation of a number.  There is no difference, as far as an `int` is concerned, between 0, 00, or 000000.

Comment: *"I wanted to perform some operations with it"* What operations? No *numeric* operation requires the leading zeros.

Comment: Am I experiencing deja vu? I swear I just saw this question earlier in the day.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i will again combine the array elements into a single element

Answer (score 0):

Convert your number to a string then use `substring()` to split it up.

```
long num = 1000000000000L;
String str = num + "";

String[] array = new String[2];

array[0] = str.substring(0, 6);
array[1] = str.substring(7);
```